# ElasticSearch query using match or term?

Tags: elasticsearch

I use match query to search the field "syslog_5424"

```
{
  "query":{
    "filtered":{

      "query":{"match":{"syslog5424_app":"e1c28ca3-dc7e-4425-ba14-7778f126bdd6"}}
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the query result:

```
{
took: 23,
timed_out: false,
-_shards: {
total: 45,
successful: 29,
failed: 0
},
-hits: {
total: 8340,
max_score: 17.623652,
-hits: [
-{
_index: "logstash-2014.12.16",
_type: "applog",
_id: "AUpTBuwKsotKslj7c27d",
_score: 17.623652,
-_source: {
message: "132 <14>1 2014-12-16T12:16:09.889089+00:00 loggregator e1c28ca3-dc7e-4425-ba14-7778f126bdd6 [App/0] - - Get the platform's MBean server",
@version: "1",
@timestamp: "2014-12-16T12:16:10.127Z",
host: "9.91.32.178:33128",
type: "applog",
syslog5424_pri: "14",
syslog5424_ver: "1",
syslog5424_ts: "2014-12-16T12:16:09.889089+00:00",
syslog5424_host: "loggregator",
syslog5424_app: "e1c28ca3-dc7e-4425-ba14-7778f126bdd6",
syslog5424_proc: "[App/0]",
syslog5424_msg: "Get the platform's MBean server",
syslog_severity_code: 5,
syslog_facility_code: 1,
syslog_facility: "user-level",
syslog_severity: "notice",
@source_host: "%{syslog_hostname}",
@message: "%{syslog_message}"
}
},
```

...

But when I change the "match" to "term", I got nothing. the content of field syslog5424_app is exactly "e1c28ca3-dc7e-4425-ba14-7778f126bdd6", but I can't find it using "term".any kind of advice would be good.

```
    {
      "query":{
        "filtered":{

          "query":{"term":{"syslog5424_app":"e1c28ca3-dc7e-4425-ba14-7778f126bdd6"}}
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What analyser are you using on field **syslog_5424**?

if it's the `standard analyser` then the data is probably being broken down into search terms.
e.g.

```
e1c28ca3-dc7e-4425-ba14-7778f126bdd6
```

is broken down into:

```
e1c28ca3
dc7e
4425
ba14
7778f126bdd6
```

When you use **match query**, your search string will also be broken down - so a match is made.

However when you use a **term query**, the search string won't be analysed. i.e. you are looking for `e1c28ca3-dc7e-4425-ba14-7778f126bdd6` in the 5 individual terms - **it's not going to match**.

So - my recommendation would be to update your mapping to use `not_analyzed` - you wouldn't normally need part of a UUID, so turn off all analysis for this field.